# Renaming multiple files with a bash loop

Tags: string, bash

I am trying to replace all instances of "heat_1" to "heat_21" in the following file names, but I am having issues with producing a consise regex that covers all four files:

```
5JUP_N2_UUCGCU_heat_1.out  5JUP_N2_UUCGCU_heat_1.rst  mdcrd_heat_1  mdinfo_heat_1
```

I did the following, but the file extensions ".out" and ".rst" got removed. How do I write the regex so that they don't get removed?

```
for i in ls *
do 
mv $i ${i/heat_*/heat_21}
done
```

Comment: There is no regex in your code. Aside from this, I would first (with your approach) calculate the extension, and after removing the part after `heat_`, I would re-attach the missing extension. Other possibilities are to use `rename` instead of `mv` (if your platform has it), or code the script in `zsh` (which comes with a nice `zmv` command for exactly this purpose).

Answer (score 1):

With Perl's standalone `rename` (or sometimes `prename`) command:

```
rename -n 's/heat_1/heat_21/' *
```

Output:

```
rename(5JUP_N2_UUCGCU_heat_1.out, 5JUP_N2_UUCGCU_heat_21.out)
rename(5JUP_N2_UUCGCU_heat_1.rst, 5JUP_N2_UUCGCU_heat_21.rst)
rename(mdcrd_heat_1, mdcrd_heat_21)
rename(mdinfo_heat_1, mdinfo_heat_21)
```

If output looks okay, remove `-n`.

---

With `bash`:

```
for i in *; do echo mv "$i" "${i/heat_1/heat_21}"; done
```

Output:

```
mv 5JUP_N2_UUCGCU_heat_1.out 5JUP_N2_UUCGCU_heat_21.out
mv 5JUP_N2_UUCGCU_heat_1.rst 5JUP_N2_UUCGCU_heat_21.rst
mv mdcrd_heat_1 mdcrd_heat_21
mv mdinfo_heat_1 mdinfo_heat_21
```

If output looks okay, remove `echo`.

Comment: Thanks. I was using the wildcard symbol because I wanted a way to target the numbers. I'm trying to rename a bunch of directories that range from heat_1 to heat_20. I also like how you use echo to make sure your code works before changes actually take place. Will try that next time.

Answer (score 0):

In your regular expression, you are changing "heat_*" to "heat_21".

So, you are changing every occurence of *string "heat_" and all letters after* it to "heat_21". If you will place "heat_1" in a middle of your file name you will see, that after running your initial code, all the rest of the file name (after "heat_") will be gone.

So, to fix your problem, you should use proper regexp:

```
for i in *
do
mv "$i" "${i/heat_?/heat_21}"
done
```

I replaced * in your regular expression with ?, which stands for any character. But, since you only want to switch "heat_1" to "heat_21", you can replace '?' with '1'.

Comment: Thanks the ? is a nice way to mark single characters. What if I had more than one digit though?